# Display content based on Select Menu dropdown change

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, selection

I'm currently using the following to display an input field when I change a dropdown menu selection:

```
<select id="delivery_country" name="d_country" onchange="
 if (this.selectedIndex==14){
  this.form['statesUSA'].style.visibility='visible'
 }else {
  this.form['statesUSA'].style.visibility='hidden'
 };">
```

However, this only changes the input form element called "statesUSA".

If I want to show the div that this form element is inside, how do I do this?

For the record, my HTML reads:

`<div id="usa">
<input type="text" id="statesUSA" />
</div>`

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `document.getElementById(id)`

this:

```
<select id="delivery_country" name="d_country" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex==14){document.getElementById('usa').style.visibility='visible'}else {document.getElementById('usa').style.visibility='hidden'};">
```

Comment: Hmm. For some reason this isn't working. My current code on the select menu is: if (this.selectedIndex==14){document.getElementById['usa'].style.visibility='visible'}else {document.getElementById['usa'].style.visibility='hidden'};

Comment: And the HTML is:  <div name="usa" id="usa" class="inputs" style="visibility:hidden;">

Comment: don't use [] use parenthesis: () here: instead of ['usa'], use ('usa')

Comment: Many many thanks for everyones help with this. Out of interest, if I were to have multiple if statements (3 in total) - how would I do this? All my experiments so far are failing.

Comment: @mcgarriers consider using functions and call them on the `onchange`

Comment: Hi jackJoe. As you can probably tell Javascript isn't my best language. Is there any chance you could put something together and show me how best to do this? I would really appreciate it. Just a basic bit of code to get me on the right path. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: @mcgarriers define a function in a javascript block (like `function doThis() { your code here with multile ifs, or maybe case statements }` and then use it at the select like this: `onchange="doThis()"`. If the original answer solved your problem, please accept my answer by clicking the √ next to it :)